# Ways to stop people from uploading GIFs with injections in them?

Tags: php, security, image-processing, gd, code-injection

I have a PHP website where people can fill out help-tickets.  It allows them to upload screenshots for their ticket.  I allow gif, psd, bmp, jpg, png, tif to be uploaded.  Upon receiving the upload, the PHP script ignores the file extension.  It identifies the filetype using only the MIME information, which for these filetypes is always stored within the first 12 bytes of the file.

Someone uploaded several GIFs, which when viewed with a browser, the browser said it was invalid, and my virus scanner alerted me that it was a injection (or something like that).  See below for a zip file containing these GIFs.

I don't think only checking header info is adequate.  I have heard that an image can be completely valid, but also contain exploit code.

So I have two basic questions:

1. Does anyone know how they did injected bad stuff into a GIF (*while still keeping a valid GIF MIME type*)?  If I know this, maybe I can check for it at upload time.
2. How can I prevent someone from uploading files like this?

   - I am on shared hosting so I can't install a server-side virus
     scanner.
   - Submitting the info to a online virus scanning website
     might be too slow.
   - Is there any way to check myself using a PHP class that checks for these things?
   - Will resize the image using GD fail if it's not valid?  Or would the exploit still slip through and be in the resized image?  If it fails, that would be ideal because then I could use resizing as a technique to see if they are valid.

---

**Update:** Everyone, thanks for replying so far.  I am attempting to look on the server for the GIFs that were uploaded.  I will update this post if I find them.

**Update 2:** I located the GIFs for anyone interested.  I put them in a zip file encrypted with password "123".  It is located here (be careful there are multiple "Download" buttons on this hosting site -- some of them are for ads) http://www.filedropper.com/badgifs.  The one called 5060.gif is flagged by my antivirus as a trojan (TR/Graftor.Q.2).  I should note that these files were upload prior to me implementing the MIME check of the first 12 bytes.  So now, I am safe for these particular ones.  But I'd still like to know how to detect an exploit hiding behind a correct MIME type.

---

**Important clarification:** *I'm only concerned about the risk to the PC who downloads these files to look at them.*  The files are not a risk to my server.  They won't be executed.  They are stored using a clean name (a hex hash output) with extension of ".enc" and I save them to disk in an encrypted state using an fwrite filter:

```
// Generate random key to encrypt this file.
$AsciiKey = '';
for($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
    $AsciiKey .= chr(mt_rand(1, 255));

// The proper key size for the encryption mode we're using is 256-bits (32-bytes).
// That's what "mcrypt_get_key_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)" says.
// So we'll hash our key using SHA-256 and pass TRUE to the 2nd parameter, so we
// get raw binary output.  That will be the perfect length for the key.
$BinKey = hash('SHA256', '~~'.TIME_NOW.'~~'.$AsciiKey.'~~', true);

// Create Initialization Vector with block size of 128 bits (AES compliant) and CBC mode
$InitVec = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
$Args = array('iv' => $InitVec, 'key' => $BinKey, 'mode' => 'cbc');

// Save encoded file in uploads_tmp directory.
$hDest = fopen(UPLOADS_DIR_TMP.'/'.$Hash.'.enc', 'w');
stream_filter_append($hDest, 'mcrypt.rijndael-128', STREAM_FILTER_WRITE, $Args);
fwrite($hDest, $Data);
fclose($hDest);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post what your virus scanner detected.  There are a handful of vulnerabilities in various image parsers.  In any case, you need a virus scanner server-side to protect against this type of thing.  Surely your host provides one?

Comment: I remember this post helping me deal with the problem back in the day
http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/67-PHP-security-exploit-with-GIF-images.html

Comment: An excellent question, to which I would also like to know the answer. +1

Comment: Related: vulnerabilities have been reported [in ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=20629) in the past.

Comment: [This is a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3099273/472495) to the problem - run your image handling in a separate, sandboxed process.

Comment: _The files are not a risk to my server. They won't be executed_. I wouldn't be too sure about that. If you resize an (unencrypted) image using GD, that could potentially execute code on the server if a vulnerability in GD exists. I thought that was the purpose of your question, until you added this update `:)`

Comment: Your zip foes doesn't seem to be readable by Info-ZIP.  I get an error when I try to uncompress: "need PK compat. v5.1 (can do v4.6)"

Comment: @halfer, That is a very good point.  If such an exploit existed, that would be super bad for the web because images are resized all the time.

Comment: Faced this problem years ago. Solved by rewriting content to new file using GD library (get graphic content from one & write to another gif file). it didn't work with animated GIFs. Malicious code is mostly placed in "comment" field inside GIFs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the **first question**, you'll never really know if you're not able to retrieve any logs or the images in question, because there are many things these exploit may have targeted and depending on what's the target the way the exploit was put into the file can be completely different.

**Edit:** *W32/Graftor* is a [generic name](https://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan_w32_graftor.shtml) for programs that appear to have trojan-like characteristics.

After opening the file `5060.gif` in a hex editor, I noticed the program is actually a [renamed windows program](http://img560.imageshack.us/img560/3516/izprog1.png). Although it's not a browser exploit and thus harmless unless it's actually opened and executed, you'll have to make sure it isn't served with the MIME type defined by the uploader because a user may still be tricked into opening the program; see the answer to the second question.

As for the **second question**: to prevent any exploit code from being run or a user, you'll have to make sure all files are stored with a safe extension in the filename so they are served with the correct MIME type. For example, you can use this regular expression to check the file name:

```
if(!preg_match ( '/\\.(gif|p(sd|ng)|tiff?|jpg)$/' , $fileName)){
    header("415 Unsupported Media Type");
    die("File type not allowed.");
}
```

Also make sure you're serving the files with the correct Content Type; make sure you don't use the content type specified with the uploaded file when serving the file to the user. If you rely on the Content-Type specified by the uploader, the file may be served as `text/html` or anything similar and will be parsed by the users' browser as such.

Please note that this only protects against malicious files exploiting vulnerabilities in the users' browser, the image parser excluded.

If you're trying to prevent exploits against the server you'll have to make sure that you won't let the PHP parser execute the contents of the image and that the image library you are using to process the image does not have any known vulnerabilities.

Also note that this code does not defend you against images that contain an exploit for the image parser used by the users browser; to defend against this, you can check if `getimagesize()` evaluates to true as suggested by Jeroen.

Note that using `getimagesize()` alone isn't sufficient if you don't check file names and make sure files are served with the correct `Content-Type` header, because completely valid images can have HTML / PHP code embedded inside comments.

Comment: Bad idea, someone can just change the file extension or content type.

Comment: This is a start, but doesn't protect against theoretical vulnerabilities in GD2/ImageMagick/etc.

Comment: @Jeroen I've added a warning about the Content Type. As for the file extension, that's exactly what this code tries to prevent.

Comment: No, I meant someone could take a .exe file and rename it to .gif, which would pass your inital code.

Comment: @Jeroen You're right, the first code assumes that the server will serve files with these extensions with the right `Content-Type` that's been associated with the image at the server - which may not be the case.

Comment: Just to be clear, I was just commenting about the initial code you provided; now that your answer has been edited, it's good advice indeed!

Comment: The Content-Type reported by PHP is set by the client, so it cannot be relied on.

Comment: @Jacco That's what I meant when I wrote "don't use the content type specified with the uploaded file". Do you think I should further clarify it?

Comment: @user1419007, I didn't read it from your answer. The do not rely on the content header part is clear, but the reason behind it could use some improvement.

Comment: I've added an additional clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10865274/revisions#spacer-38101729-7b6f-4efb-af3b-f1732584b21b

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function for this. If the image is invalid it will simply return `false`.

```
if (getimagesize($filename)) {
    // valid image
} else {
    // not a valid image
}
```

It's worth noting that this isn't 100% safe either, but it's the best you can do as far as I know.

Read more [about this here](http://ha.ckers.org/blog/20070604/passing-malicious-php-through-getimagesize/).

Comment: You're correct about "not being 100% safe".  It's absolutely possible to put exploit code in a perfectly legal image file.

Comment: Thanks for that article. It is very informative.  I don't believe getimagesize() is ok to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about image formats, but recreating the images and then storing the result, I feel has a good chance of eliminating unnecessary tricky stuff. Especially if you strip all the meta data like comments and all the other types of optional embedded fields that some image formats support.

Comment: This would be likely to remove embedded PHP, but recreating the image could theoretically trigger a low-level buffer overflow vulnerability (such as the ImageMagick one I posted under the question).

Comment: while true, by that logic, all software should be avoided because all software is vulnerable to buffer overflows. unless you're implying the image libs have an especially poor track record and should be avoided on that basis.

Comment: I think this suggestion is probably the a good idea -- to completely re-create the image that's uploaded.  I guess the question is will GD (or insert-image-library-here) fail if there is an exploit, or will it it unwittingly pass the exploit on to the re-created file?

Comment: @chris: not avoided, no - it's just that with other classes of web input (strings, ints) we know how to filter before doing something with them. So files that require non-trivial low-level processing (e.g. image resizing) _feel_ a bit riskier since they haven't gone through the checks we'd do in PHP. Possible solutions to dealing with malicious files: for large installations a separate upload server with no access to the database, and maybe for smaller ones, a sandboxed process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try phpMussel on any php script that accepts uploads. The file will be scanned using ClamAV signatures, plus some internal heuristic signatures that look for this type of intrusion specifically.

Answer (score 0):

1) You're never going to know exactly what the problem was if you deleted the .gif and your A/V didn't write a log.

Q: Is the .gif in question still on the server?

Q: Have you checked your A/V logs?

2) There are many different possible exploits, which may or may not have anything directly to do with the .gif file format.  Here is one example:

- http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/67-PHP-security-exploit-with-GIF-images.html

3) To mitigate the risk in this example, you should:

a) Only upload files (*any* files) to a *secure* directory on the server

b) Only serve files with specific suffixes (.gif, .png, etc)

c) Be extremely paranoid about anything that's uploaded to your site (especially if you then allow other people to download it from your site!)

Comment: Yes, I updated the first post to include a ZIP file that contains the gif(s) with a virus.

Answer (score 0):

On very usefull tip to prevent problems with injected PHP came from my host's system admin: I have a site where people can uploaded their own content. I wanted to make sure the directory where uploaded images are served from doesn't run any PHP. That way someone could even post a picture named "test.php" and it would still NEVER be parsed by PHP if it was in the upload directory. The solution was simple: In the folder the uploaded content is served from put the following .htacess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.$ - [NC]
php_flag engine off
```

This will switch off the PHP engine for the folder, thus stopping any attempt to launch any PHP to exploit server side vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but may be useful for somebody.
You may try such approach:

```
//saves filtered $image to specified $path
function save($image,$path,$mime) {
    switch($mime) {
        case "image/jpeg"   : return imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($image),$path);
        case "image/gif"    : return imagegif(imagecreatefromgif($image),$path);
        case "image/png"    : return imagepng(imagecreatefrompng($image),$path);
    }
    return false;
};
```