# Up to date secure PHP image uploading

Tags: php, security, file, uploading

I need to implement a secure PHP file upload script. What current methods are you using to ensure that your script is secure?

I will be whitelisting allowed extensions, and ensuring that Apache is running as the user to avoid the need for 777 permissions by default.

Uploaded files will be images, and I have MySQL access. Users will need to be able to see their files once uploaded.

Thanks!

Comment: Whitelisting extensions is, frankly, a moronic security system. It's trivial for someone to rename `nastyvirus.exe` to `cutekittens.jpg`. Changing apache's uid is also fairly useless. A properly implemented download script wouldn't care who the actual user is - it'd restrict the user to their files only anyways via some external means of ownership assignment, e.g. a database.

Comment: @MarcB, +1.  Always, always check MIME types.

Comment: just upload the images into a temp directory and then copy/resize a new version from uploaded pic in the images directory and empty the temp

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just to clarify though, I'm uploading not download files from the server. Surely running Apache as the user and eliminating the need for 77 permissions on the upload folder makes the system much more secure? Wes, can MIME types not be faked? Thanks!

Comment: anything can be faked, but at least doing server-side mime-type determination is a bit safer than trusting the `['type']` field supplied by the remote user, let alone the remote filename. perfectly valid mimetype can have malicious things embedded, but at least you're making it a smidge harder for the attacker to do anything, rather than leaving the front door wide open with "hackme" stickers all over.

Answer (score 1):

For some advise to avoid malicious files from being uploaded, see the answers to [Ways to stop people from uploading GIFs with injections in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865202/ways-to-stop-people-from-uploading-gifs-with-injections-in-them).

The other important thing is to avoid SQL injection. Any data that can modified by an attacker (cookies, user-agents, query string, POST data (including uploaded file names), headers, dynamic pathnames etc.) should not be used without being passed trough `mysql_real_escape_string` or the [MySQLi equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) first. In case of integers, use the `intval()` function.

Comment: Hi. SQL injection should not be too much of an issue as only the filename will be recorded in the database, via PDO and prepared statements. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Do as you're saying to check file extensions, but to verify that an uploaded file with a proper extension is actually what it says it is, try [running it through imagemagick using the verify command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php).  It's a simple solution that seems one of the very few ways to guarantee without a shadow of a doubt that the image is as it claims to be.

Also, make use of the PHP Function [is_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) to add an extra level of security.

Hopefully it goes without saying, but PDO should be used for database transactions on all aspects of PHP.

Finally, remember that if you use javascript for any validation, that it can easily be overridden by a semi-competent web user.  Client-side validation is more responsive to the user, but always back it up with proper server-side checks.